# Carga de archivos en LinkedList y suma de duplicados en Java

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, jtable, jfilechooser

Estoy haciendo un programa con JFileChooser, ya tengo el código y compila bien.
Se carga un archivo con valores separados por * en donde viene el nombre y cantidad, por medio de un JTable muestro la información cargada del archivo y guardo la información en una LinkedList.

La idea es que al cargar un segundo archivo, los nombres que vienen duplicados se sume la cantidad y se actualice la JTable, los nombres que no se repiten los debe agregar como un campo nuevo en la JTable.

```java
public class Archivo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    LinkedList<Articulos> articulo = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Articulos> repetidos = new LinkedList<>();
    
    public Archivo() {
        initComponents();
    }

public void cargarArchivo(File archivo) {

        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(archivo);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            for (Articulos r : articulo) {
                if (br.readLine().equals(r.getNombreArticulo())) {
                }
            }

      
            String linea;

            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String arreglo[] = linea.split("\\*");
                if (arreglo.length > 0) {
                    Articulos a = new Articulos();
                    a.setNombreArticulo((arreglo[0].trim().replace(".", "").toUpperCase()));
                    a.setCantidad(Integer.parseInt(arreglo[1].trim()));
                    articulo.add(a);
                    
                }

            }
            llenarTabla();
```

Pero al momento de cargar un segundo archivo, en lugar de sumarme las cantidades del segundo archivo, me suma las cantidades que ya están ingresadas del primer archivo.
Para esto cree una nueva LinkedList con el nombre de repetidos y ejecuto el siguiente for.

```java
    Articulos se, se2;
    for (int x = 0; x < articulo.size(); x++) {
        se = articulo.get(x);
        for (int y = 0; y < articulo.size() && !repetidos.contains(articulo.get(x)); y++) {
            se2 = articulo.get(y);
            int suma;
            if (articulo.get(x).equals(articulo.get(y))){
              suma = se.getCantidad() + se2.getCantidad();
              System.out.println(suma + se.getNombreArticulo());  
            }
        }
    }
```

Coloque el *System.out.println* solo para ver que esta imprimiendo en pantalla, pero en realidad necesito que actualice mi método *llenarTabla();*

El primer archivo contiene lo siguiente:

ARTICULO * CANTIDAD

> CAMISAS*5
>
> PLAYERAS*10
>
> PANTALONES*15

Y el segundo:

> CAMISAS*20
>
> PLAYERAS*25
>
> PANTALONES*22
>
> CALCETINES*10

el resultado del *System.out.println* me da lo siguiente:

```
10 CAMISAS
20 PLAYERAS
30 PANTALONES
```

Solo suma el primer archivo cargado, cuando en realidad debería tomar en cuenta el segundo archivo y sumar los repetidos, mostrando como resultado

```
CAMISAS*25
PLAYERAS*35
PANTALONES*37
CALCETINES*10
```

Alguien tiene una idea de como debo hacer la suma de cantidades al cargar dos archivos?

Comment: No entiendo demasiado tu código porque está incompleto y no se puede saber cuando se ejecuta cada cosa, pero si lo que quieres tener es una lista de cosas sin repetir, asociados con una cantidad, la estructura recomendada para eso es un Map.

Luego si quieres agregar esos datos y mostrarlos en un JTable, pues recorres el map y vas agregando el key y el value a la tabla.

Comment: disculpa pero en el primer ciclo for con un if dentro ¿que es lo que hace?,

Comment: en el system.out.println() tienes que colocar la vaariable suma